# Why nc doesn't response even if the "w" option set?

Tags: network, bash, command-line

For some servers:

```
nc -w 1 -z x.x.x.x 22
```

doesn't work. It has no response, but is looking like very busy: only <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> can help.

So `-w 1` seems to be a useless option, to specify the timeout.

Does somebody know what is going wrong: how specify a real timeout?

Comment: Might be a bit off topic for the apple, might try unix, however. adding `nc -w 5 -l 1222` works for me. the timer does not take effect until a connection is made.

Comment: I thought it is only issue of apple's version of netcat